# `mousemove` and triggering a custom event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In a `mousemove` event:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function( e ){
    console.log( e.pageX );
    console.log( e.pageY );
});
```

as you can see, we can use `pageX` and `pageY` to get the `x` and `y` co-ordinates of mouse position. But, what I want is to trigger a custom event of mine on `mousemove` and would like to get these `pageX` and `pageY` values in that custom event of mine. To be more clear, what I would like to do is:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(){
    $(document).trigger('myevent');
});

$(document).on('myevent', function( e ){
    // console.log( e.pageX );
    // console.log( e.pageY );
});
```

Is there any way to access these `pageX` and `pageY` in `myevent`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) allows to pass additional data via its arguments. You can call

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function( event ){
    $(document).trigger('myevent', event);
});
```

Now you have access to the whole original `event` object within your custom event code.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create a custom event like

```js
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var event = $.Event('myevent', {
    pageX: e.pageX,
    pageY: e.pageY
  });
  $(document).trigger(event);
});

$(document).on('myevent', function(e) {
  log(e.pageX + ':' + e.pageY)
});

var log = function(message) {
  var $log = $('#log');
  $log.html(message)
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```