# jQuery Mousemove: throw event into another element at coordinates

Tags: jquery, html, css, mousemove, magnify

How do I persist/broadcast the mouse movements of one element into another (with exacting coordinates)?  Note that the zoom effect of `DIV B`should work when the *generated* jQuery `.mousemove()` is triggered.  See code in snippet or [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/bp03s0rm/) for further context.

```js
// Code by Magnify JS maintained by thdoan
// http://thdoan.github.io/magnify/
// https://github.com/thdoan

var native_width = 0;
var native_height = 0;

//Now the mousemove function
$(".magnify").mousemove(function(e) {
  //When the user hovers on the image, the script will first calculate
  //the native dimensions if they don't exist. Only after the native dimensions
  //are available, the script will show the zoomed version.
  if (!native_width && !native_height) {
    //This will create a new image object with the same image as that in .small
    //We cannot directly get the dimensions from .small because of the 
    //width specified to 200px in the html. To get the actual dimensions we have
    //created this image object.
    var image_object = new Image();
    image_object.src = $(".small").attr("src");

    //This code is wrapped in the .load function which is important.
    //width and height of the object would return 0 if accessed before 
    //the image gets loaded.
    native_width = image_object.width;
    native_height = image_object.height;
  } else {
    //x/y coordinates of the mouse
    //This is the position of .magnify with respect to the document.
    var magnify_offset = $(this).offset();
    //We will deduct the positions of .magnify from the mouse positions with
    //respect to the document to get the mouse positions with respect to the 
    //container(.magnify)
    var mx = e.pageX - magnify_offset.left;
    var my = e.pageY - magnify_offset.top;

    //Finally the code to fade out the glass if the mouse is outside the container
    if (mx < $(this).width() && my < $(this).height() && mx > 0 && my > 0) {
      $(".large").fadeIn(100);
    } else {
      $(".large").fadeOut(100);
    }
    if ($(".large").is(":visible")) {
      //The background position of .large will be changed according to the position
      //of the mouse over the .small image. So we will get the ratio of the pixel
      //under the mouse pointer with respect to the image and use that to position the 
      //large image inside the magnifying glass
      var rx = Math.round(mx / $(".small").width() * native_width - $(".large").width() / 2) * -1;
      var ry = Math.round(my / $(".small").height() * native_height - $(".large").height() / 2) * -1;
      var bgp = rx + "px " + ry + "px";

      //Time to move the magnifying glass with the mouse
      var px = mx - $(".large").width() / 2;
      var py = my - $(".large").height() / 2;
      //Now the glass moves with the mouse
      //The logic is to deduct half of the glass's width and height from the 
      //mouse coordinates to place it with its center at the mouse coordinates

      //If you hover on the image now, you should see the magnifying glass in action
      $(".large").css({
        left: px,
        top: py,
        backgroundPosition: bgp
      });
    }
  }
});

//http://stackoverflow.com/a/26782439/5076162 - Arun P Johny
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var event = $.Event('myevent', {
    pageX: e.pageX,
    pageY: e.pageY
  });
  $(document).trigger(event);
});

$(document).on('myevent', function(e) {
  log(e.pageX + ':' + e.pageY)
});

var log = function(message) {
  var $log = $('#log');
  $log.html(message)
};
```

```css
/*Some CSS*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.magnify {
  width: 658px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
}
/*Lets create the magnifying glass*/

.large {
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  /*Multiple box shadows to achieve the glass effect*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85), 0 0 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 40px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  /*Lets load up the large image first*/
  background: url('https://s.rrimr.com/SPSSMR/ImageCache/ImageCache.aspx?Project=S1910683&File=B10_COLOR_IMG_FANCY.jpg') no-repeat;
  /*hide the glass by default*/
  display: none;
}
/*To solve overlap bug at the edges during magnification*/

.small {
  display: block;
}
.throwMouse {
  width: 658px;
  height: 208px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Lets make a simple image magnifier -->
<div class="throwMouse">
  <h3>
DIV A:
</h3>
  Throw this element's mousemove events INTO the .catchMouse element and have it behave as though the mouse were hovering over it.
</div>
<div class="magnify catchMouse">

  <!-- This is the magnifying glass which will contain the original/large version -->
  <div class="large"></div>

  <!-- This is the small image -->
  <h3>
DIV B:
</h3>
  <img class="small" src="https://s.rrimr.com/SPSSMR/ImageCache/ImageCache.aspx?Project=S1910683&File=B10_COLOR_IMG_FANCY.jpg" width="658" />
</div>
<div id='log'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

The idea is when the mouse over the `.throwMouse` div we simulate an a mouseover event on the `.magnify` div, so we need to adjust the mouse to be 200px down to be on that div

```
$('.throwMouse').on('mousemove', function(e) {
      var event = $.Event('myevent', {
        pageX: e.pageX,
        pageY: e.pageY + 200
      });
      $(".magnify").trigger(event);

    });
```

Then we add an event listener for the created event `myevent` on the `.magnify` div beside the old event `mouseover`

```
$(".magnify").on('mousemove myevent', function(e) { //});
```

You can check which div is the target of the event by checking `event.target`

```
if($(event.target).hasClass('throwMouse')){
 //do something specific for this div
}
```

```js
// Code by Magnify JS maintained by thdoan
// http://thdoan.github.io/magnify/
// https://github.com/thdoan

var native_width = 0;
var native_height = 0;





//Now the mousemove function
$(".magnify").on('mousemove myevent', function(e) {
  //When the user hovers on the image, the script will first calculate
  //the native dimensions if they don't exist. Only after the native dimensions
  //are available, the script will show the zoomed version.
  if (!native_width && !native_height) {
    //This will create a new image object with the same image as that in .small
    //We cannot directly get the dimensions from .small because of the 
    //width specified to 200px in the html. To get the actual dimensions we have
    //created this image object.
    var image_object = new Image();
    image_object.src = $(".small").attr("src");

    //This code is wrapped in the .load function which is important.
    //width and height of the object would return 0 if accessed before 
    //the image gets loaded.
    native_width = image_object.width;
    native_height = image_object.height;
  } else {
    //x/y coordinates of the mouse
    //This is the position of .magnify with respect to the document.
    var magnify_offset = $(this).offset();
    //We will deduct the positions of .magnify from the mouse positions with
    //respect to the document to get the mouse positions with respect to the 
    //container(.magnify)
    var mx = e.pageX - magnify_offset.left;
    var my = e.pageY - magnify_offset.top;

    //Finally the code to fade out the glass if the mouse is outside the container
    if (mx < $(this).width() && my < $(this).height() && mx > 0 && my > 0) {
      $(".large").fadeIn(100);
    } else {
      $(".large").fadeOut(100);
    }
    if ($(".large").is(":visible")) {
      //The background position of .large will be changed according to the position
      //of the mouse over the .small image. So we will get the ratio of the pixel
      //under the mouse pointer with respect to the image and use that to position the 
      //large image inside the magnifying glass
      var rx = Math.round(mx / $(".small").width() * native_width - $(".large").width() / 2) * -1;
      var ry = Math.round(my / $(".small").height() * native_height - $(".large").height() / 2) * -1;
      var bgp = rx + "px " + ry + "px";

      //Time to move the magnifying glass with the mouse
      var px = mx - $(".large").width() / 2;
      var py = my - $(".large").height() / 2;
      //Now the glass moves with the mouse
      //The logic is to deduct half of the glass's width and height from the 
      //mouse coordinates to place it with its center at the mouse coordinates
      //If the mouse is on the div A make the .large DIV up a 100px.
if($(event.target).hasClass('throwMouse')){
        py -= 100;
      } 
      //If you hover on the image now, you should see the magnifying glass in action
      $(".large").css({
        left: px,
        top: py,
        backgroundPosition: bgp
      });
    }
  }
});

//http://stackoverflow.com/a/26782439/5076162 - Arun P Johny
$('.throwMouse').on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var event = $.Event('myevent', {
    pageX: e.pageX,
    pageY: e.pageY + 200
  });
  $(".magnify").trigger(event);
});

$(document).on('myevent', function(e) {
  log(e.pageX + ':' + e.pageY)
  //$(".magnify").mouse
});

var log = function(message) {
  var $log = $('#log');
  $log.html(message)
};
```

```css
/*Some CSS*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.magnify {
  width: 658px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
}
/*Lets create the magnifying glass*/

.large {
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  /*Multiple box shadows to achieve the glass effect*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85), 0 0 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 40px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  /*Lets load up the large image first*/
  background: url('https://s.rrimr.com/SPSSMR/ImageCache/ImageCache.aspx?Project=S1910683&File=B10_COLOR_IMG_FANCY.jpg') no-repeat;
  /*hide the glass by default*/
  display: none;
}
/*To solve overlap bug at the edges during magnification*/

.small {
  display: block;
}
.throwMouse {
  width: 658px;
  height: 208px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Lets make a simple image magnifier -->
<div class="throwMouse">
  <h3>
DIV A:
</h3>
  Throw this element's mousemove events INTO the .catchMouse element and have it behave as though the mouse were hovering over it.
</div>
<div class="magnify catchMouse">

  <!-- This is the magnifying glass which will contain the original/large version -->
  <div class="large"></div>

  <!-- This is the small image -->
  <h3>
DIV B:
</h3>
  <img class="small" src="https://s.rrimr.com/SPSSMR/ImageCache/ImageCache.aspx?Project=S1910683&File=B10_COLOR_IMG_FANCY.jpg" width="658" />
</div>
<div id='log'>

</div>
```

Comment: KId this looks good.  Could you please give an explanation of exactly what you did here?  Also, is there anyway you could "catch" the `.large` element and re-position it to just underneath the mouse (when it is visible only).

Comment: @AlexanderDixon I am a little late, I added some explanation and a solution for your last question.

Comment: @KId you really understand this jQuery event stuff and have been a great help.  The final step, to put it all together, it to Hide div B somewhere off the page flow (perhaps absolute positioning), but keep all the functionality that you've implemented thus far.  So like give `DIV B` a negative -9999 margin-left. and then give `pageX` the amount it needs to be over the hidden `DIV B`.